# Filebeat Service will not start on RHEL 7

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat, rhel7

I have a trouble/problem with my Filebeat installation.

When I try it to start with "`service filebeat start`", it says "Starting Filebeat". After "`service filebeat status`" I get 4 PIDs **(until here everything looks "normal")**:

```
[root@(Server) run]# service filebeat status
Filebeat is running with pid: 30650 30657 30658 30659
```

But after checking the PID, we see that it is not running:

```
[root@(Server) run]# ps -ef | grep 30650
root     30665 31360  0 16:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 30650
```

Trying to start it with systemctl doesn't help:

```
[root@(Server) run]# systemctl start filebeat
Job for filebeat.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status filebeat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Status says:

```
[root@Server run]# systemctl status filebeat
● filebeat.service - LSB: start and stop filebeat
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/filebeat; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Tue 2017-09-26 16:30:33 CEST; 1min 41s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 32118 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/filebeat start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 26 16:30:33 Server... systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop filebeat...
Sep 26 16:30:33 Server... filebeat[32118]: Starting Filebeat
Sep 26 16:30:33 Server... su[32119]: (to user) root on none
Sep 26 16:30:33 Server... systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/filebeat.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Sep 26 16:30:33 Server... systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop filebeat.
Sep 26 16:30:33 Server... systemd[1]: Unit filebeat.service entered failed state.
Sep 26 16:30:33 Server... systemd[1]: filebeat.service failed.
```

Does somebody has any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was "chown permissions". I installed filebeat not as root and the "data" directory had root user & group ownership. After changing that, it runs and starts automatically after boot.

Regards